# Spring batch integration- Moving a file

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch integration. I need to move a file from one local directory to another. I tried using inbound channel and out bound channel. I'm not able to move it.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="incomingfiles"
      directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/input"
      filename-pattern="*.txt">

<file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="outgoingfiles" 
      directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/output">
```

I am using correct spring namespace handler but i get unable to load namespacehandler[file]. I have added spring integration jars too. Not a mavenproject.

Kindly help me. or Can we move a file using batch instead of spring integration? IF yes, could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Could you print the whole error "unable to load namespacehandler[file]" ? Is it a stacktrace ? do you ahve it at compile time or runtime ?

Comment: Are you really sure that you have `spring-integration-file` java in classpath? And let us know why simple `File.renameTo(File)` or `Files.move()` isn't enough for you?